# How to Properly Select Specific Fields in Mikro-ORM for MongoDB to Avoid Circular References?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, fastify, mikro-orm

I'm using [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) with [Fastify](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/) and [Mikro-ORM](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/installation) (for MongoDB) and I'm facing an issue related to circular references when trying to serialize my entities. Here are simplified versions of my primary entities for context:

```js
@Entity()
export class Group {
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id: number;

  @Property()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User)
  admins = new Collection<User>(this);
}

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id: number;

  @Property()
  username: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Group, group => group.admins)
  groups = new Collection<Group>(this);
}
```

The circular reference issue arises when serializing a `Group`, which contains an `admins` array. Each `admin` in the array is a `User` entity, which in turn has a `groups` collection. This results in a loop: `Group -> User -> Group -> User -> ...`.

When I tried to fetch specific fields using Mikro-ORM's `fields` option:

```js
const groups = await this.em.find(
  Group,
  {},
  {
    fields: ['_id', 'name', 'admins._id', 'admins.username'],
    populate: ['admins'],
  },
);
```

The result was an array of empty admin arrays:

```json
[ [], [], [], ... ]
```

However, when I added the `admins` property along with other specific fields:

```js
const groups = await this.em.find(
  Group,
  {},
  {
    fields: ['_id', 'name', 'admins', 'admins._id', 'admins.username'],
    populate: ['admins'],
  },
);
```

The result reintroduced the circular reference by including the `groups` property for each `User`:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "_id": "some-id",
      "username": "exampleUser",
      "groups": [ /* ... group data ... */ ]
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
]
```

I've successfully addressed this problem using custom DTOs to transform the entities before sending them to the client. However, I'm curious if there's a more intuitive method using field selections or any other built-in Mikro-ORM capabilities to handle such scenarios.

Is there a way in Mikro-ORM to precisely select fields without inadvertently reintroducing circular references? Any insights or best practices regarding this would be highly appreciated!

#### Error Encountered:

When attempting to serialize the results, the following error is encountered:

```json
{
  "type": "RangeError",
  "message": "Maximum call stack size exceeded",
  "stack": "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MetadataStorage.getMetadata (path\to\file.ts:168:22)
    at MetadataStorage.getExposedMetadatas (path\to\file.ts:108:17)
    at MetadataStorage.getExposedProperties (path\to\file.ts:116:17)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.getKeys (path\to\file.ts:461:54)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (path\to\file.ts:150:25)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (path\to\file.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (path\to\file.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (path\to\file.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (path\to\file.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (path\to\file.ts:327:31)"
}
```

This error is indicative of a circular reference during serialization and is the main issue I am trying to resolve.